# App not showing in app Testflight after apple update

Tags: testflight

I am trying to upload the build to AppStore but it is not showing in Testflight or anywhere. Its shows there for a few seconds and dispear. I am getting the Xcode project from unity. I have tried multiple apps and multiple unity versions and multiple accounts as well all builds are disappearing. And I even tried uploading an old Xcode project that was successful 2 days ago. I even created empty unity project and tried uploading but it still disappears. It all happened after apple's latest update 12 hours ago. anyone else having the same issues?

Answer (score 0):

I am. I've loaded 5 builds and even changed the version number of the app. The new version number showed for a few minutes and then disappeared. No build was in the dropdown though.

Update:

Just got off the phone with Apple. There's an "import issue" that I need to wait 24hrs to clear. I did receive an email from them about the error and assumed it related to only one upload but it seems to have jammed up my whole upload/Testflight.

Comment: So did you finally uploaded the build or not?
The same is happening with me, build is disappearing after few minutes. 
I didn’t receive a single email yet.

Comment: After I got off the phone with Apple I uploaded another build. That build finally came through about 6 hours later. Check your spam for the email or give Apple a call. They picked up quick.